# Disjoint Refinement

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Prove that for any countable family of infinite sets from $\mathbb{N}$, $A = \{A_n \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, there is a disjoint refinement $B = \{B_n \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of infinite sets, that is for every $n$, $B_n$ is an infinite subset of $A_n$, and all the $B_n$'s are pairwise disjoint.

Also prove the version for $\mathbb{R}$: for any family (with cardinality not surpassing $\mathbb{R}$'s) of sets from $\mathbb{R}$, $A = \{A_r \colon r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ such that $|A_r| = \mathbb{R}$ for all $r$, there is a disjoint refinement $B = \{B_r \colon r \in \mathbb{N}\}$, that is for every $r$, $B_r$ is a subset of $A_r$, $|B_r| = \mathbb{R}$ for all $r$, and all the $B_r$'s are pairwise disjoint.

Sorry for my complete lack of knowledge in latex.

Comment: I edited your post. You can see its code to learn how to type it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an idea for the first one.

1. put the least element of $A_0$ into $B_0$.
2. put the least element of $A_0$ not already assigned into $B_0$, and the least element of $A_1$ not already assigned into $B_1$.
3. put the least element of $A_0$ not already assigned into $B_0$, the least element of $A_1$ not already assigned into $B_1$, and the least element of $A_2$ not already assigned into $B_2$.
4. etc.

(By "not already assigned" I mean not already put into some $B_i$ in some previous step or in some previous part of the same step.)

Another way to think about this is that if we change the enumeration of the $A_i$'s so that each one is repeated infinitely many times, then we only have to choose a single element from each one.  This approach can be generalized to solve the second problem also: enumerate the $A_i$'s in order type $|\mathbb{R}|$ so that each one is repeated $|\mathbb{R}|$ many times, and then from each $A_i$, choose an element that was not already chosen from any of the previous $A_i$'s (using the fact that every proper initial segment of the well-ordering has fewer than $|\mathbb{R}|$ many elements.)  I don't know if the Axiom of Choice is really needed here.

Comment: That's an interesting question, whether or not the axiom of choice is needed for that. If there would be a counterexample I think it would either be in something like a Solovay model, or the Feferman-Levy model. But it might be something much more delicate that will ultimately require a new model to be designed.

Comment: Suppose (in the absence of AC) all of the $A_n$ are the same amorphous set.  There won't be even two disjoint infinite sets to serve as $B_n$'s.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Good point.  One could still wonder about the case where all of the $A_n$'s are sets of reals, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Arnold Miller's solution [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/qual/2004-8.pdf).